# Подскажите различия между Solidity 0.4.0 и 0.7.5

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smart-contract

Начал изучать курс по solidity с версией 0.4.0, но хотел бы перейти на 0.7.5

Есть отрывок кода

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract test {
    string public strStr = "Lol";
    function counting(string _x) public view {
        strStr = _x;
    }
}
```

При просмотре через (к примеру) MyCrypto выдает строку "Lol" и есть функция для замены строки.

А вот немного измененный код на 0.7.5, но в нем ничего не работает [image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.5;

contract test {
    string public strStr = "Lol";
    function counting(string memory _x) public {
        strStr = _x;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что нужно поменять?

Comment: А какой результат ожидается от выполнения метода со спецификатором "view"?
Он по определению ничего не изменяет - даже компилятор должен выдать ошибку.

Comment: Вы вызвали метод через транзакцию (eth_sendTransaction) или просто через вызов метода (eth_call)?

Comment: @MadJackal не понял вас )

Comment: Кажется я понял, но это довольно странно. Надо всего лишь вписать в ABI "constant": true и все покажет. Но почему по умолчанию он это не пишет?

Comment: Метод смарт-контракта может быть вызван либо просто при обращении к смарт-контракту (в RPC API это метод eth_call), либо в теле транзакции (в RPC API это метод eth_sendTransaction). В первом случае никаких изменений в блокчейне (включая состояние хранимых переменных смарт-контракта) не будет - любые изменения происходят исключительно при выполнении транзакций.